# Algorithm Question: How does linked list gets updated using Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, class

Here is a solution to merging two linked lists. In the code, we use place_holder to avoid cases such as dealing with null values. However, this is not intuitive as we only update `tail` throughout the code but we return `place_holder.next` at the end.

When are we updating `place_holder`? within the while loop we're only working with list1 and list2 nodes and updating the tail. But when are we changing the values of place_holder?

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val: int = 0, *vals: int) -> None:
        self.val = val
        self.next = ListNode(*vals) if vals else None

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        s = f"{str(self.val)}"
        if self.next:
            s += f" -> {self.next}"
        return s

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:

        place_holder = ListNode()
        tail = place_holder

        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                tail.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                tail.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            tail = tail.next

        if list1 is None:
            tail.next = list2

        if list2 is None:
            tail.next = list1

        return place_holder.next
```

Comment: ?? tail starts out as placeholder and is moved, you return the originals placeholders next because that one is the first element non the less - all other values are added to tail's next wich starts out as placeholder and then is moved downstream as needed.... you may want to put this into pythontutor.com and debug it for 2 short lists to get clear what is what....

Comment: @PatrickArtner did not know that website existed. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can be seen visually in [Python tutor](https://pythontutor.com/)

Before the while loop, place_holder and tail are assigned to the same object i.e. ListNode():

```
place_holder = ListNode()
tail = place_holde
```

In the first iteration of the while loop, tail.next is assigned to either list1 or list2 based upon which branch taking in the if condtion i.e.

```
if list1.val < list2.val
   tail.next = list1            # tail assigned to list1
   list1 = list1.next
else:
   tail.next = list2             # tail assigned to list2
   list2 = list2.next
```

This also assigns place_holder.next to the same list since place_holder and tail are assigned to the same object in the first iteration.

After the if condition, tail is assigned to a different object i.e.

```
tail = tail.next        # this causes place_holder and tail
                        # to no longer be assigned to the same object
```

So in subsequent iterations of the while loop, tail keeps being updated in the while loop but place_holder is not changed (since place_holder and tail are no longer assigned to the same object)

Since place_holder.next keeps it assignment at the end of the function the return either returns list1 or list2.

Comment: I see now it's more evident now. Could you please elaborate on how tail gets assigned to a different object in ```tail = tail.next```. Are ```tail.next = list1``` and ```tail = tail.next``` the same ```tail.next```?

Comment: @JoeyJoestar -- in traversing the linked list, tail points to the current node in the list.  tail.next points to the next one.  By assigning tail = tail.next you step to the next node to make it the current one.